# 'ng add @angular/material' produces error, why?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli

When I try to install angular material components by using the `ng add` command I get an `package already installed` error.

> $ ng add @angular/material
> Skipping installation: Package already installed
>
> Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/schematics/tasks'
> Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/schematics/tasks'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
> at Object.  (C:\Users\emilbonnek\node_modules@angular\material\schematics\ng-add\index.js:10:17)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
> at new ExportStringRef(C:\Users\emilbonnek\Documents\private\ultimating\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js:18:25)
> at NodeModulesEngineHost._resolveReferenceString
> (C:\Users\emilbonnek\Documents\private\ultimating\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\node-module-engine-host.js:94:21)
> at NodeModulesEngineHost.createSchematicDescription(C:\Users\emilbonnek\Documents\private\ultimating\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\file-system-engine-host-base.js:179:34)
> at SchematicEngine.createSchematic (C:\Users\emilbonnek\Documents\private\ultimating\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\src\engine\engine.js:219:38)

I don't have access to any of the modules, so I don't think its because the package is already installed, however it could be that I have simply misunderstood something about schematics.

I am on angular CLI version 8.0.3 and same for devkit/core and devkit/schematics. I am completely sure I am running the command in the right directory.

Why is the command not doing as it is supposed to? any help is appreciated.

Comment: I had the same issue. Installing material `npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations` and running `ng add @angular/material` worked for me.

Comment: which version of angular cli you re using/

Comment: @AniruddhaDas 8.0.3, it's in the post too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there's something wrong with your node_modules, as it doesn't find `@angular-devkit/schematics/tasks`. I'd clean it and reinstall again to avoid any unexpected problems, and try again.

Adopting the schematics paradigm means that we do not edit the `package.json` directly anymore, and use `ng add` and `ng update` only, but as Aj1 said, sometimes it works installing the package and running the schematic after that.

Answer (score 17):

I ran into this issue as well with the latest version of Material UI and Angular CLI. I was only able to run the add command after installing material manually as @Aj1 mentioned above:

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations
ng add @angular/material
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have installed globally: @angular-devkit/schematics-cli

`npm install -g @angular-devkit/schematics-cli`

This way, it would work before npm install