# ng add @angular/material fails with "Cannot read property 'endTag' of null"?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to add Angular Material to my Angular 9 project so I can use the autocomplete functionality. Unfortunately, while following [the installation guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#install-angular-material), I cannot get past the first step in installing the Angular Material module. I attempted to resolve the problem following the steps listed in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56657158/ng-add-angular-material-produces-error-why#comment99885022_56657158). Here are the steps I took, and my package.json below for reference.

1. `npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations`
2. `ng add @angular/material`

Output from these commands is as follows:

```
chantelle@penny:~/projects/nereus_bos/2020-bos-frontend/bos-frontend$ npm install @angular/material --save
npm WARN @aws-amplify/datastore@2.1.0 requires a peer of @react-native-community/netinfo@^5.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @aws-amplify/core@2.3.0 requires a peer of @react-native-community/netinfo@^5.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular/material@9.2.4
updated 1 package and audited 1729 packages in 10.141s

54 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

chantelle@penny:~/projects/nereus_bos/2020-bos-frontend/bos-frontend$ ng add @angular/material
Skipping installation: Package already installed
? Choose a prebuilt theme name, or "custom" for a custom theme: Deep Purple/Amber  [ Preview: https://material.angular.io?theme=deepp
urple-amber ]
? Set up global Angular Material typography styles? No
? Set up browser animations for Angular Material? Yes
UPDATE package.json (1563 bytes)
✔ Packages installed successfully.
Cannot read property 'endTag' of null
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "bos-frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/localize": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.9",
    "@aws-amplify/pubsub": "^2.1.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.1.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^3.0.11",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "ngx-spinner": "^9.0.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.9",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you mean it, but you just have to use `ng add @angular/material`. The way you described it in your question it seems like you also installed angular material and its dependencies by hand before running `ng add`. BTW, I don't think it could cause any issues if you have done that. But I've tried it here with a brand new project (just the `ng add` part) and it successfully installed material in the app. It seems there are some more things wrong with your project. Is it an old project? Was it upgraded from an old angular version? Have you use ng update to do the updating?

Comment: Hi @julianobrasil! Thanks for your input, as it turns out the issue was that I had not properly created an "angular material module". I solved the problem by following the steps detailed in this blog post: https://codemeals.com/angular-tutorials/angular-material/

Comment: I'm not sure how you followed that blog post, but it's quite out-of-date. I hope you've made the necessary modifications to the process described there (especially the imports that should be made in a deep path fashion instead of the deprecated way of importing everything from `@angular/material`). Also `hammer.js` now get its own module.

Comment: I am facing with same problem. What is the solution? link is broken?

Answer (score 1):

The error is likely caused by duplicate ending tags.

Check your .html file, remove the duplicated ending tags like `</html>,</body>`.

Comment: In my case, it wasn't a duplicated ending tag, but it **was** a problem in my `src/index.html` file. (A code generator I wrote had inserted a literal `\n` instead of a newline character, as intended.